# Saw a link that probably isn't relavant

Tags: bug

I was poking around in the help center and saw this:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask-beta

I'm pretty sure this is left over from the EE.SE beta or chip hacker days. It doesn't look like its relevant anymore since I cant add beta questions, in that case some of the stuff in the help center should probably be revised.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's a network-wide setting, and either it doesn't get disabled or it's new and the disable logic doesn't apply yet.

Comment: Is this area 51 stuff?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290401/how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-is-listed-in-every-site-s-help-centre

Comment: I'll start checking the meta before I start asking questions, I didn't realize that most of this stuff comes from the top down

Comment: *Most* elements, aside from the visual theme and some site-specific text, are shared between sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been reported on [Meta.SE from January 28, 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290401/how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-is-listed-in-every-site-s-help-centre). I'm going to guess that it's a low-priority bug given that it hasn't even gotten an official response in 2 months.